# Proving that a set is not compact by contradiction

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

for a function $f : X \to Y $ with $X$ being set of continuous function from $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, X equiped with the standard Euclidian metric and $C([0,1])$ with $d(f,g)=\max \{|f(t)-g(t)|: 0\leq t \leq 1\}$

Show that $A=\{f\in X : f(0)=0\}$ is not compact,

My thought is that since $A$ is not bounded then it can't be compact, but am I right to think so?

Comment: Looks okay to me

Comment: You don't need a contradiction. Just show that $A$ is unbounded and you are done.

Comment: What is $R[0,1]?$

Comment: If $X$ is a space of functions, is the standard Euclidean metric the $L^2$ norm, or is is $X=C([0,1])$ with your max norm? Basically, your whole first paragraph is unclear.

Comment: Yes. In a metric space, if F is a finite set of bounded open balls then any subset of $\cup$F is bounded. Let G be the set of all bounded open balls.  Then G is an open cover of A, but no finite F $\subset$ G can cover A because A is unbounded. For further reading, look up the  Arzela-Ascoli Theorem. My edit was for typos. If you don't want "max" italicized, use \max.